# MySQL: One to many relational table, return all select command into single json column

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a header table that contains id and the name of people. And then I have many tables containing the detail of that particular people, such as phone number, address, sex, birth place, etc.

How can I return the SELECT command after joining all those tables, but return it only in one json populated column?

The output should be like: {"id":''236732", "name":"John Doe", "phone": "4875696", ... }

Can I really do it?

table_header## Heading ##

### id    name

### 1    John Doe

### 2    Jack Sparrow

3    Jane Doe

### ....

### ...

### ....

5000    Jane Silk

table_detail
id    phone_number
1    34574358
2    68538039
3    7537689237
....
...
...
5000   89457987

table_detail2
id    address
1    xxxxxxxx
2    xxxxxxxx
3    xxxxxxxx
....
....
....
5000   xxxxxxx

table_detail3
....
....
.....
....
....
table_detail10 (with almost the same structure, with more than 5000+ record each)

I want to make one additional field with json type at the table_header that contains all of the detail information of particular user.

Comment: Just convert it to JSON in PHP it has a function specifically for that.

Comment: Please provide your schema for all tables, as well as the intended output for several records, not just one.

Comment: Good answer. But I have server problem when I have to join more than 10 tables with 100+ column of the users detail, with more than 5000+ record. It will cause a huge amount of processing time. I wonder if there is a way to return all the detail data of the user efficiently. @Nick

Comment: The processing has to occur somewhere, either in PHP or MySQL. You'd be transferring basically the same amount of data from MySQL to PHP so that wouldn't affect it. But without seeing full table schema and your query, it's impossible to give a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "as a single line" it reminds me of a problem I had where the echo was multiple json objects but is being sent as one string and I had to parse it in the client JS like this:

```
var lines = JSON.parse('[' + this.responseText.replace(/}{/g, '},{') + ']');
```

The problem is that there is no seperator between objects, and this makes an array out of it. Is that why you want it as one single json object? If so this might be a workaround for you. The php is pretty simple like Nick said:

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. It works. I decided to join all the tables first using SELECT command for all the rows ( indexing the foreign key so it would save processing time ), json_encode each of the row, and then inserting it to the corresponding row. Thank you for your help and @Nick